# How Can I set layout size in Streamlit?

Tags: python, folium, streamlit

Is it possible to set height and width in Streamlit layout? I know that there is possibility to set layout='wide'and 'centered' but its not enough for me. Map is too big when  I use wide, too small when I use centered. When I set a size folium Map there is a blank,white space between layout and map. I would like to set this size without blank spaces.

wide: https://gyazo.com/0af46f5efc80ff079410a9aeae1d38b0
centered: https://gyazo.com/22bac904af28f6ebed0e9989e131dcf2

Comment: This may help. https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/custom-render-widths/81/8

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit map is just a wrapper around `st.pydeck_chart`. This helps making a map chart easily but also has some limitations like setting height and width.

The best option if you want to control the height and width of the presented map is to use the `st.pydeck_chart` which has a height and width argument.

Here is a code to create a map using  `st.pydeck_chart`:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pydeck as pdk


height = 500
width = 500

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(1000, 2) / [50, 50] + [37.76, -122.4],
    columns=['lat', 'lon'])

st.pydeck_chart(pdk.Deck(
     map_style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
     initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
         latitude=37.76,
         longitude=-122.4,
         zoom=11,
         height=height,
         width=width
     ),
     layers=[
         pdk.Layer(
             'ScatterplotLayer',
             data=df,
             get_position='[lon, lat]',
             get_color='[200, 30, 0, 160]',
             get_radius=100,
             auto_highlight=True
         ),
     ],
 ))
```

Output with height=500 and width=500:

[image: Out1]

Output with height=100 and width=100:

[image: out2]

**Note** - `st.map` creates a scatter plot chart on top of a map but using `st.pydeck_chart` gives us more flexibility and options in map creation and design.

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function `_max_width_(80)` in your app.py and you’ll be able to always start with wide-mode. More on [Custom Render Widths](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/custom-render-widths/81)

```
def _max_width_(prcnt_width:int = 75):
    max_width_str = f"max-width: {prcnt_width}%;"
    st.markdown(f""" 
                <style> 
                .reportview-container .main .block-container{{{max_width_str}}}
                </style>    
                """, 
                unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )
```